# How to animate clicked li from its current position to top position and hide all li

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have list of different list items so when i click on specific item from list it should move from its current position to top position using jquery animate and at the same time hide remaining list items using jquery.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".menu").click(function() {
    $("li").animate({
      top: '2px'
    }, 'slow');
  });
});
```

```css
ul>li {
  list-style-type: none;
  line-height: 34px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="menu">
  <li>Account</li>
  <li>Profile</li>
  <li>History</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: After hiding other li do you want this li back to show?

Comment: @SagarKodte  no because i will keep sidebar so when mouseover on it only remaining items will display

Comment: I have done this but without animation let me add it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can show click element by adding **addClass** and css to added class and simultaneously you can hide others li by jquery `hide()`. Hope it helps. I'm just adding the animation to it.

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $("li").click(function() {
        $(this).addClass('top');
        $('li').hide();
    });
});
```

```css
ul>li {
  list-style-type: none;
  line-height: 34px;
}
.top{
  display:inline-block !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="menu">
  <li>Account</li>
  <li>Profile</li>
  <li>History</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Inorder  to animate top the element has to be able to take the css property `top`. So far I made the element to be capable enough to take the property `top` and I animated it to top while reducing the opacity using `transition`. **These jquery this are done for the sibling `li` elements of the clicked one.**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".menu li").click(function() {
    $(this).siblings('li').animate({
      top: '-60px'
    }, 'fast');
    $(this).siblings('li').css({
      'opacity': '0'
    });
  });
});
```

```css
ul>li {
  list-style-type: none;
  line-height: 34px;
  position: relative;
  top: 10px;
  transition: all 2s ease;
}

.menu {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="menu">
  <li>Account</li>
  <li>Profile</li>
  <li>History</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: i want clicked li should not dissappear only remaining li

Comment: So you want to keep the clicked li and hide the rest?